# Why should a Li-Mak Test on Squared Standardized Residuals be preferred over a ARCH LM Test or Ljung-Box Test on Squared Residuals?

Tags: time-series, garch, diagnostic

If I didn't misunderstand the literature, the predominant approach to test for autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity in (G)ARCH models is to apply the ARCH LM test of Engle or the Ljung-Box test on the squared (non-standardized) residuals.

Alternatively, the Li-Mak test can be applied on the squared standardized residuals. Why should this test be preferred over the others? Is it because we assume for GARCH models that the **standardized** residuals are iid? If yes, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARCH-LM and Ljung-Box (LB) tests are to be applied on raw data* or on residuals* of a model that does not allow for ARCH patterns. Meanwhile, Li-Mak test is to be applied on standardized residuals of a model that does allow for ARCH patterns, e.g. a GARCH(1,1) or an ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model. There is no situation where both ARCH-LM & LB and Li-Mak tests are applicable, so you never need to choose between better and worse tests, only between valid and invalid tests (which is an obvious choice).

*squared in case of the Ljung-Box test

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This means ARCH-LM and LB tests are to be applied on e.g. raw returns (or on residuals). If ARCH effects are identified I can fit e.g. a GARCH model and afterwards I can test for any remaining conditional heteroscedasticity using the Li-Mak test. Is that right?

Comment: @Programm_Newbie9196, exactly. This is what you would also find in [other threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22li-mak%22) that mention Li-Mak test. (Many of these contain my answers.)

Comment: Amazing. I've already seen many of your answers and they helped me a lot. Thanks again and enjoy your sunday!